# Express.js - Parameter validation pattern

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

I have few REST endpoints and searching for a smart way to validate the request parameters.

My structure looks like.

```
router.route('/data/add').post(async (request, response, next) => {

  if (parameterValidator.isInt(request.body.id) === false) {
     logger.info('/data/add -> id parameter validation fails');
     return response.status(400).json({ error: `bad request` });
  }
  if (parameterValidator.validate(request.body.param1) === false) {
      logger.info('/data/add -> param1 parameter validation fails');
      return response.status(400).json({ error: `bad request` });
  }
  ....
}
```

parameterValidator.js

```
function validate(parameter) {
  if (parameter === null || parameter === '' || parameter === undefined) {
      return false;
  }
}

function isInt(parameter) {
  const x = parseFloat(parameter);
  return !isNaN(parameter) && (x | 0) === x;
}

module.exports = {
  validate: validate,
  isInt: isInt
}
```

Is there a smarter way to validate the parameter in the controller. I have in some controllers up to 20 parameters and huge blocks to validate the request parameters.

When I do it like this in the parameterValidator.js the controller function does not stop the request.

```
function validate(parameter, response) {
  if (parameter === null || parameter === '' || parameter === undefined) {
      return response.status(400).json({ error: `bad request` });
  }
}
```

Comment: Think about to use a validation library, like [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi). It makes live easier, especially for more complex validations. (Do not use `var`, use `let` or `const`)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, you can use validation middleware for a cleaner codebase. Here I'm sharing a sample validation middleware that uses [Joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0).
You can modify it as needed.

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const validate = async (req, res, next) => {
        // create validation schema object
        const schema = Joi.object({
            id: Joi.number().required(),
        });
// schema options
    const options = {
        abortEarly: false, // include all errors
        allowUnknown: true, // ignore unknown props
        stripUnknown: true, // remove unknown props
    };

        // validate request body against schema
        const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body, options);

        if (error) {
            // on fail return comma separated errors
            const errorMessage = error.details
                .map((details) => {
                    return details.message;
                })
                .join(', ');
            next(new Error(errorMessage));
        } else {
            // on success replace req.body with validated value and trigger next middleware function
            req.body = value;
            return next();
        }
    }
```